# How should I go about miniaturization of patch antenna?

Tags: antenna, patch-antenna

I am working on a microstrip patch antenna for 1 GHz resonant frequency. I want the antenna to be ideally less than 6 cm for both length and width. Normally, a 1 GHz microstrip antenna would have 14-15 cm sides.

I have tried shorting wall and increasing the dielectric with some success, but meandering, slotting, pins, fractal, etc. seem to be very iterative and I'm not able to land on 1 GHz resonant frequency after I start with the necessary dimensions for the antenna. (can't even make it go below 2.5 GHz resonant frequency).

Hence, I want to know if there is any ideal set of methods to ease the iteration process, or a few rules of thumb from professionals to design this out. If it helps, I'm working this out on HFSS.

Edit: These are important parameters for the microstrip antenna: Ideally, -20 dB Return Loss, Narrowband is okay (1-10 MHz), but it must operate at 1 GHz. Decent positive gain (~2-3 dB far field) is fine. Around 6cm * 6 cm side is the maximum I want it to be.

Comment: Hm, you will need to tell us how *good* your miniature antenna needs to me; building a bad antenna is easy, just don't terminate your transmission line ;) Also, the bandwidth the antenna needs to achieve makes a difference (1MHz around 1GHz? 200 MHz around 1 GHz?)

Comment: Ideally, -20 dB Return Loss, Narrowband is okay (1-10 MHz), but it must operate at 1 GHz. Decent positive gain (~2-3 dB far field) is fine.

Comment: if narrowbandness is OK, have you looked into chip antennas?

Comment: I have not, actually. I see now that they are the sorts used in portable electronic devices, so they sound promising. However, could you tell me what kind of drawbacks to expect? My application requires antennas for near-field imaging of an object of around 30 cm radius, so they will be used as receivers as well.

Comment: Basically, using scatter field data to generate an image of the object's dielectric profile.